# Org mode: Display only tasks under a specific headline in the agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

As part of a weekly review, I'd like to have a block agenda that displays only the subtrees under the "Inbox" heading in my inbox.org file (which is part of `org-agenda-files`). To do that, I believe I would need to use a user-defined function.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(; Weekly Review block agenda
    ("r" . "Weekly Review")
    ("r1" "Review unprocessed items in Inbox" 
      my/org-get-items-under-headline "Inbox"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Inbox items to process:")))
    ; ...
   ))
```

I need help writing the `my/org-get-items-under-headline` function, which should take the parameter `heading` and return all the subtree headlines under it. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure what kind of format `org-agenda-custom-commands` is looking for.

My inbox.org file looks relatively simple.

```
* Inbox
** Task 1
   :PROPERTIES:...
** Task 2
   :PROPERTIES:...
* Processing
```

So the block agenda should only display the Task 1 and Task 2 headlines.